# Why can php://input be read more than once despite the documentation saying otherwise?

Tags: php, post, inputstream

The PHP documentation [states](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) that `php://input` can only be read once.

In my application I need to read it twice, once for authentication purposes and once for actually processing the content, and both functions are handled by different, independent modules. The crazy thing is: **it works**.

Can I count on this working everywhere, or is this a fluke in my version of PHP (5.2.10)? The only documentation I can find about this is the one that states that it shouldn't work, with no version limitation mentioned.

---

Following Dennis' hunch, I did this test:

```
$in = fopen('php://input', 'r');
echo fread($in, 1024) . "\n";
fseek($in, 0);
echo fread($in, 1024) . "\n";
fclose($in);
echo file_get_contents('php://input') . "\n";
```

Curling:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888/tests/test.php -d "This is a test"
This is a test

This is a test
```

Apparently it's limited to one read **per open handle**.

---

A little more digging revealed that indeed `php://input` can only be read once, ever, **for PUT requests**. The above example used a POST request.

Comment: ... and now, 4.5 year later, PHP 5.6 officially [supports](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) reading from `php://input` more than once, and even seek operations :)

Comment: For those of us not yet on PHP 5.6, wrapping `file_get_contents('php://input')` in a function that caches the result and calling that instead is a viable work-around.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A little inspection of the source code yields the answers.

First, yes, you're limited to one read per handle because the underlying stream does not implement the `seek` handler:

```
php_stream_ops php_stream_input_ops = {
    php_stream_input_write,
    /* ... */
    "Input",
    NULL, /* seek */
    /* ... */
};
```

Second, the read handler has two different behaviors depending on whether the "POST data" has been read and stored in `SG(request_info).raw_post_data`.

```
if (SG(request_info).raw_post_data) {
    read_bytes = SG(request_info).raw_post_data_length - *position;
    /* ...*/
    if (read_bytes) {
        memcpy(buf, SG(request_info).raw_post_data + *position, read_bytes);
    }
} else if (sapi_module.read_post) {
    read_bytes = sapi_module.read_post(buf, count TSRMLS_CC);
    /* ... */
} else {
    stream->eof = 1;
}
```

So we have three possibilities here:

1. The request body data has already been read and stored in `SG(request_info).raw_post_data`. In this case, since the data is stored, we can open and read multiple handles for `php://input`.
2. The request body data has been read, but its contents were not stored anywhere. `php://input` cannot give us anything.
3. The request data hasn't been read yet. This means we can open `php://input` and read it only once.

**NOTE: What follows is the default behavior. Different SAPIs or additional extensions may change this behavior.**

In case of POST requests, PHP defines a different POST reader and a POST handler depending on the content-type.

**Case 1.** This happens when we have a POST request:

- *With content-type `application/x-www-form-encoded`*. `sapi_activate` detects a POST request with a content-type and calls `sapi_read_post_data`. This detects the content-type and defines the POST reader/handler pair. The POST reader is `sapi_read_standard_form_data`, which is immediately called and just copies the request body to `SG(request_info).post_data`. The default post reader `php_default_post_reader` is then called, which fills `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` if the ini setting `always_populate_post_data` is set and then copies `SG(request_info).post_data` to `SG(request_info).raw_post_data` and clears the first. The call to the handler doesn't matter here and is deferred until the superglobals are built (which may not happen, in case JIT is activated and the superglobals are not used).
- *With an unrecognized or inexistent content-type*. In this case, there's no defined POST reader and handler. Both cases end up in `php_default_post_reader` without any data read. Since this is a POST request and there's no reader/handler pair, `sapi_read_standard_form_data` will be called. This is the same function as the read handler the content type `application/x-www-form-encoded`, so all the data gets swallowed to `SG(request_info).post_data`. The only differences from now on is that `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is always populated (no matter the value of `always_populate_post_data`) and there's no handler for building the superglobals.

**Case 2.** This happens when we have a form request with content-type "multipart/form-data". The POST reader is `NULL`, so the handler, which is `rfc1867_post_handler` acts as a mixed `reader/handler`. No data whatsoever is read in the `sapi_activate` phase. The function `sapi_handle_post` is eventually called in a later phase, which, in its turn calls the POST handler. `rfc1867_post_handler` reads the request data, populates `POST` and `FILES`, but leaves nothing in `SG(request_info).raw_post_data`.

**Case 3.** This last case takes place with requests different from POST (e.g. PUT). `php_default_post_reader` is directly called. Because the request is not a POST request, the data is swallowed by `sapi_read_standard_form_data`. Since no data is read, there's not anything left to be done.

Comment: Nicely detailled answer! But, is there a good reason for this behavior, or is it simply an oversight? I.e. does it work "as intended" or "as coded"? :)

Comment: @deceze The implementation seems reasonable. application/x-www-form-encoded data is usually short, so the memory penalty for keeping it in memory is small. multipart/form-data is usually significantly bigger (e.g. includes files), it would be more onerous to have it memory. With other POST requests, I don't think it's a great idea to keep everything in memory, but it's required for backwards compatibility (old scripts only had $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA). As to other request methods, the implementation also seems reasonable -- allows the user to read the data in a stream fashion, sparing memory.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe they mean fseek() or rewind() aren't available.
Have you tried one of those functions on an opened php://input ?

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but.. what is the new question?