# Can't get 'http put' content in PHP

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js

framework is here
http://luracast.com/products/restler/

i'm using restler as restful api for my work,
when i use backbone model save to a url, it sends and update my data as json by using 'HTTP PUT' request method, and i want to get a response from what i've putted...

if it's a HTTP POST request method i can use

```
// to getting content from a POST
$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

to get my content, but cant get anything from HTTP PUT

```
// can't get anything from a PUT
function putpatients($id) {
    $post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $post_data = json_decode($post_data, true);
    echo $post_data['name'];
}
```

the browser response blank

how do i return my data as json ???

Comment: Sorry, not sure what the question is. Is the *input* blank? Is the *output* blank? Is the client-side blank?

Comment: `php://input` is a stream, if you read from it, it empties it.
Is possible you've already read from it? if that's the case, the second `file_get_contents('php://input')` would return `''`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I commented on your question, `php://input` is a stream, if you read from it, it empties it.

I've never used Restler before but looking at the few examples provided in their download, it seems to indicate the submitted data is automatically passed as a parameter to your put handler..

In Restler's [crud example](http://help.luracast.com/restler/examples/_006_crud/readme.html), the Author class has a put request like this:

```
function put($id=NULL, $request_data=NULL) {
    return $this->dp->update($id, $this->_validate($request_data));
}
```

so i'm guessing that restler has already read the `php://input` stream, and hence emptied it.

so, your put handler should maybe be more like in their example:

```
function putpatients($id, $request_data = NULL) {
    /* do something with the $request_data */
    var_dump($request_data);
}
```

> Edit: There's actually a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107624/why-can-php-input-be-read-more-than-once-despite-the-documentation-saying-othe) from @deceze that talks about why reading twice from php://input doesn't work - for PUT requests - which explains why your code worked with a POST request. Either way, you should really use the facility provided by Restler rather than re-inventing the rest wheel.

Comment: oh my god it's working... i used to use this function       function putpatients($id, $data = NULL) {
    /* do something with the $request_data */
    var_dump($data);
}     but return nothing,  it's all about param name. okay i got it.

Comment: @crapthings. hmmm, I don't think the actual name of the parameter  should change anything, might have been a different problem. But hey, if it ain't broke..

Answer (score 0):

Does the developer tool of your choice (firebug etc.) show a response?

If so it could help if you put `echo json_encode($post_data['name']);` instead of your echo.

Comment: chrome   i have used var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); then what i get is string(0) ""

Answer (score 0):

try to use print_r() function for displaying the values of the variable example:

```
print_r($post_data);
```

Comment: blank variable contents? what's wrong ?  i am sure i make a HTTP PUT REQUEST_METHOD  but  i just cant return what i have putted.